# What to say to a dog to make it go away?

Tags: phrase-request

What should I say to a dog when I want to make him or her go away (e.g. when I'm jogging in the park)? What name should I call him or her? I thought to say "Hi dog, go away", but it would be strange to say. Anyone has a good idea?

Comment: Every dog is different but you might try saying in a firm and commanding tone, "GO!" while pointing away from you with a fully outstretched arm.

Comment: I would say *Shoo! Go away!*

Comment: Artemyss, there is no strict rule for that context. What to say is up to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Shoo! Scram!**

From NOAD:

> **shoo** (*exclamation*)
>   a word said to frighten or drive away a person or animal.
>
> **scram** (*verb*)
>   [ intrans., usu. in imperative ] *informal* go away from or get out of somewhere quickly : *get out of here, you miserable wretches — scram!*

One children's book put it this way:

> Your fun is over! Now Scram, Scoot, and while you're at it, Vamoose!
>   (from *The Adventures of Remmington the Dog: An Unexpected Friend* by Holly Redfern)

Comment: How do you pronounce "Shoo"?

Comment: The same as you would pronounce "shoe", only with a sharper tone in your voice. It's also like "shoot" without the "t" at the end.

Comment: @Artemyss: [British](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/pronunciation/british/shoo_5) and [American](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/pronunciation/american/shoo_5). And [British English](http://shtooka.net/listen/eng/to%20shoo) again.

Comment: *Scram* is more likely in American English.

Answer (score 1):

> I thought to say "Hi dog, go away", but it would be strange to say.
>   Anyone has a good idea?

That sounds a bit awkward. Just saying "go away", on its own, would be fine.